# When did the use of œ in French start?

Tags: historical-linguistics, diacritics

*I am very new to Linguistics, so please, let me know if my question is not worded correctly!!*

I'm fluent in (Canadian) French, and œ has always been a little weird to me. It's found every now and then, in words like sœur (sister) and œuf (egg). I *do* know that it has origins in Latin. Around what time did œ start being used in French?

Comment: Do you mean the letter or the sound?

Comment: Letter, very sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Given that the transition from Vulgar Latin to (Old) French was gradual, and that manuscripts from those times generally employ an awful lot of abbreviations – including, but by no means limited to, joining up letter sequences like _oe_ and _ae_ into _œ_ and _æ_ – I’m not sure if there’s any way to say exactly when _œ_ started being used in French. Probably it was there from the beginning. The difference is that at some point, the orthography was codified, and _œ_ gained letter status, rather than just being an optional ligature used in manuscript writing.

Comment: As for me, such **œ, eux, œu, etc.** are **prettiness** of the French spelling **)**